# ItemTemplate button shall select the correct item

Tags: wpf, listview, itemtemplate

I have a ListView and an own ItemTemplate for it:

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

    <Button Content="Delete Article"
            Click="Button_Click"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ArticleID}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ArticleName}"/>

   </StackPanel>
 </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

If the user clicks on the button, the item should remove from the listview. My problem is that the click on the button doesn't select the item in it's row.

Therefore, you could select the 2nd item in the listview and click on the 1st item's 'delete button' and the 2nd item will remove from the listview instead of the 1st item as I would expect.

So one approach could be: every click on the 'delete button' will select the item which creates the button but I don't know how to handle this.

Maybe there is a better way to solve this...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is the common problem that lots of people face(i have too). So my suggestion is on button click event try to find out the to which listview item this button belongs to. and then remove that item. It is happening because click has been handled by the button and it is not able to reach to the listview.

Comment: @loop how can I find out which item belongs to the clicked button?

Comment: I don't remember from top of head right now.. so just google it you will find it. It is something like finding the parent of from datatemplate.. (sorry I am not using my computer)

Comment: Why you you pick the answer that requires a change to the the XAML when you have an answer that requires no change to the XAML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple approach would be to bind the Button's `Tag` property to the current item

```
<DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Tag="{Binding}"
                Content="Delete Article" Click="Button_Click"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ArticleID}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ArticleName}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

and then use that in the Click handler to remove the item:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var article = (Article)((Button)sender).Tag;
    Articles.Remove(article);
}
```

Assumed that `Articles` is an ObservableCollection of your article item class.

Answer (score 0):

You can pick up the DataContext then delete the row from the source
Need to use an ObservableCollection to notify the UI

```
    private void ButtonDelete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = (Button)sender;
        Fld fld = (Fld)btn.DataContext;
        Folders.Remove(fld);
    }
```